# Cannot get override method in derived (googlemock-fixture) class with fallback to base fixture class to work

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++, more used to C and python, but google was not my friend this time.

I have a baseclass which implements some googlemock fixtures implemented in 2 generic classes (a baseclass and a parameterized class which derives from that baseclass) and a TEST_P function using the parameterized fixture.
Since the parameterized fixture is used to test 2 implementations I put the fixture-classes and the TEST_P in a baseclass cpp-file (+ hpp file) and the specific parameter-tables in 2 specific cpp files.
This works like a charm.

But... now we want to extend one of the implementations so that it needs a specific implementation of a function which is defined in the generic baseclass. For the other implementation the generic implementation is still correct.

So what I want is to override the generic implementation for only 1 of the 2 test-cpp files.

Initially (without override) I had the following in the hpp:

```
class MyBaseClass : public ::testing::Test
{
    protected:
       // boring fixture setup stuff
       virtual void test( void );
}

class MyParametrizedBaseClass:
    public MyBaseClass, 
    public::testing::WithParmInterface< std:tr1::tuple< /* parameter definition */ > >{
    protected:
        // some custom assert method definitions
}
```

baseclass.cpp file:

```
MyBaseClass::test( void )
{
    cout << "This is the baseclass implementation" << std::endl;
}

...

TEST_P( MyParametrizedBaseClass, TestName )
{
     test();
     // other googlemock checks not needed for this question
}
```

And in the 2 specific implementations I have just the parameter tables:

```
std:tr1::tuple< /* parameter definition */ > const TableName[] = {
    //table implementation
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P( Name, MyParameterizedBaseClass, ::testing::ValuesIn( TableName ) );
```

Again up to now this works.

Now for ... lets call it impl_1 ... we want test to do the following (this code does not work since the definition for MyParameterizedBaseClass::test is not found):

impl_1.cpp:

```
void MyParameterizedBaseClass::test( void )
{
    cout << "This is the impl_1 implementation" << std::endl;
}
```

The first thing I did after seeing that the compiler misses the definition of MyParameterizedBaseClass::test was replace MyParameterizedBaseClass with MyBaseClass, but then it sees it as a redefinition (which it indeed is).

So next I googled and found the 'override' key word and adapted the MyParameterizedBaseClass definition so it looks like this:

```
class MyParametrizedBaseClass:
    public MyBaseClass, 
    public::testing::WithParmInterface< std:tr1::tuple< /* parameter definition */ > >{
    protected:
        // some custom assert method definitions
        void test( void ) override;
}
```

But when I do that I get the error:
Baseclass.hpp:[linenumber]: error: expected ';' before 'override'
And in the specific implementation for impl_1 it still says that no test function is declared in MyParameterizedBaseClass

And if I (knowing up front that it is wrong) put the ';' before 'override' as suggested, I get: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'override' with no type

Next I removed the 'override' keyword and recompiled.
Now the compiler is satisfied, but the linker fails on impl_2 since there I don't have an implementation of MyParameterizedClass::test.
And that is true, since I want to have the default implementation of test for that.
(To complete the description: Yes it works again if I also implement test for MyParameterizedBaseClass in impl_2.cpp)

So my question is: what am I doing wrong?

Environment: Linux with GCC 4.4.2 (pretty old I know, but that is the version my company has)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding declaration in `MyParametrizedBaseClass` was a good move.
Problem is that you have used C++11 feature `override` and based on code like this:

```
std:tr1::tuple< /* parameter definition */ >
```

(`tr1`) indicates that you are using C++03 with ["technical report one"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1), so keyword `override` is unknown. That is why compiler complains: `error: expected ';' before 'override'`

So just remove `override` keyword and it should be fine.

Comment: I tried that and the compiler likes it. But the linker does not since it misses in that case the MyParemeterizedBaseClass implementation of test for the implementation that still should use the default implementation (impl_2.cpp)

Comment: do you have definition `void MyParameterizedBaseClass::test( void )`? If yes and you have still linker issue, do a rebuild or clean before building.

Comment: In the header I now have that.
I will try doing a clean build.

Comment: Still fails on the linker (which is probably also old, knowing my company).

I'm probably forced to implement `MyParameterizedBaseClass::test` for impl_2.cpp as well and let that implementation call the MyBaseClass implementation. Drawback of that is that whenever there comes an impl_3.cpp we are forced to this implemenation <sad face>.

@MarekR: thanx for your help.

Comment: `In the header I now have that.` this is a problem.  You can't have this kind of definitions of methods in headers (there are some exceptions). This will end with linker double definition issue.